# Find the solutions of a functional equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations, even-and-odd-functions

If $f$ is an even function defined in the interval $(-5,5)$, find the number of real values of $x$ satisfying the equation $$f(x) = f(\frac{x+1}{x+2})$$
I solved it as $$f(x) = f(-x) = f(\frac{x+1}{x+2})$$ $$x = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$$ $$-x = \frac{x+1}{x+2}$$ $$x = \frac{-1±\sqrt5}{2},\frac{-3±\sqrt5}{2}$$
But I saw in many books as $$f(x) = f(-x) = f(\frac{x+1}{x+2})$$ and $$f(x) = f(-x) = f(\frac{-x+1}{-x+2})$$
So, I am confused between these solutions. Could you please tell me which one is correct?

Comment: $f(x)=f(y)$ does not imply that $x=y$.

Comment: Yes but that is a case right?

Comment: This question only makes sense if the wording is changed to: "Find the number of real values of $x$ satisfying the equation $f(x) = f(\frac{x+1}{x+2})$ for **every** even function." If that is the question, then I believe your method is correct and the books' is wrong. BTW, the roots in all your answers should be $\sqrt{5}$, not $\sqrt{3}$.